# Scroll view touch detection

Tags: iphone

I have a problem in the `touchesMoved` handler with a view that is added onto a `UIScrollView`. I add a number of labels to the scroll view. Each of these labels contain some text and, on swiping my finger on the labels, I have to play a specific file for that text.

If I just add the view onto the window directly, I get all of the touch events in `touchesMoved` without any problem. When I add my view onto the `UIScrollView` and then add this to the window, there is some lag in the `touchesMoved` handler. I am not getting continuous touch points in `touchesMoved` as with the normal view. As a result, while swiping the finger from the view, it happens that some labels are missed.

Is the problem due to scroll view? The same code runs perfectly in normal conditions (without a scroll view).

Does anyone have any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView sets a timer on touchDown to be able to know if it should handle scrolling or if it should pass the events on to subviews.

There is a property on UIScrollView for controlling this behaviour:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL delaysContentTouches
```